# Wicket: Ajax callback onTimer() method not called

Tags: ajax, wicket

I use wicket 1.5 to develop a webapplication. I have three webpages, the homePage, the ParentWebpage and a Panel. When I setup an AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior in the ParentWebpage and call in the callback function onTimer() the Panel, every thing is alright.But in the panel is also an AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior and the callback function onTimer is never called, but why??

Here my example:

HomePage.java

```
BookmarkablePageLink bookmarkablePageLink = new BookmarkablePageLink("linkToCurrentDiagnosePage", TestParent.class);
bookmarkablePageLink.add("label");
item.add(bookmarkablePageLink);
```

--> now I can navigate to the TestParent class

TestParent.java

```
public class TestParent extends WebPage {
    /** The Constant logger. */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(TestParent.class);
    boolean isSet = false;
    public TestParent() {
        LOGGER.error("Parent -> Cstr");
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment("fragments", "fragment1", TestParent.this);
        fragment.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        add(fragment);

        add(new AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(1)) {

            @Override
            protected void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                LOGGER.error("Parent -> I'am here");
                if(isSet == false){
                    LOGGER.error("Parent -> I set the panel");
                    isSet = true;
                    Fragment fragment = new Fragment("fragments", "fragment2", TestParent.this);
                    fragment.setOutputMarkupId(true);
                    fragment.add(new TestChild("panel"));
                    TestParent.this.replace(fragment);
                    target.add(fragment);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

TestParent.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span wicket:id="fragments"></span>

    <wicket:fragment wicket:id="fragment1">
        FILL TEXT
    </wicket:fragment>

    <wicket:fragment wicket:id="fragment2">
        <span wicket:id="panel">[message]</span>
    </wicket:fragment>
</body>
</html>
```

TestChild.java

```
public class TestChild extends Panel {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(TestChild.class);

    public TestChild(String id) {
        super(id);
        LOGGER.error("Child -> Cstr");

        add(new AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(1)) {

            @Override
            protected void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                LOGGER.error("CHILD --> I'am here");
            }
        });               
    }
}
```

TestChild.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <wicket:panel>

    </wicket:panel>
</body>
```

OUTPUT:

```
ERROR - TestParent                 - Parent -> Cstr

ERROR - TestParent                 - Parent -> I'am here

ERROR - TestParent                 - Parent -> I set the panel

ERROR - TestChild                  - Child -> Cstr

ERROR - TestParent                 - Parent -> I'am here

ERROR - TestParent                 - Parent -> I'am here

ERROR - TestParent                 - Parent -> I'am here

ERROR - TestParent                 - Parent -> I'am here
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using real code, this is because you are creating them both with a 1 second timer. Then in your timer code you are recreating the child panel (and therefore the childs timer behaviour). The child panel never gets a chance to fire!

Comment: That is wrong. In my code I had a duration for the parent timer with 10 seconds and in the child timer 1 second. I forget to post the code with the orginally parameters. The duration of 1 Second in the parent class was only for testing. I found a solution, in wicket 6.0.0-Beta everything working fine